# SIGABRT in destructor of an exception class

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, sigabrt, throw

I was fighting with this problem for 2 days. I have a workaround but I want to understand what happens more. So let's begin. 
I have very Primitive exception class that holds an error message as a pointer to array of chars (I know about profit of std::string). I know the "rule of three" so it looks like:

*globalexceptions.hpp*

```
class FatalError {
    public:
        const char* errorMessage;
        /* WARNING:
         * "Rule of three". You see it below.
         */
        FatalError(const char* pErrorMessage);
        FatalError(const FatalError& rhs);
        FatalError& operator=(const FatalError& rhs);
        ~FatalError();
};
```

*globalexceptions.cpp*

```
FatalError::FatalError(const char *pErrorMessage):
    errorMessage(pErrorMessage)
{}

FatalError::FatalError(const FatalError& rhs){
    char* buf = new char[strlen(rhs.errorMessage)+1];
    strcpy(buf, rhs.errorMessage);
    errorMessage = buf;
}

FatalError& FatalError::operator =(const FatalError& rhs){
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;
    delete[] errorMessage;
    char* buf = new char[strlen(rhs.errorMessage)+1];
    strcpy(buf,rhs.errorMessage);
    errorMessage = buf;
    return *this;
}

FatalError::~FatalError(){
    delete[] errorMessage;
}
```

But when throwing:

```
int Config::readConfig(int argc_p, char *argv_p[])
{
    if ( argc_p != 2 )
    {
        throw FatalError ("Sick usage. Try: <file.ini>\n");
    }
```

I get "SIGABRT".

Some valgrind analysis:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
  in FatalError::~FatalError() in globalexceptions.cpp:26
Address 0x413980 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  1: operator delete[](void*) in /tmp/buildd/valgrind-3.7.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:490
  2: FatalError::~FatalError() in <a href="file:///home/gumba/Projects/cpp/backup_helper/backup_helper-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_2_in_PATH__System__Debug/../backup_helper/globalexceptions.cpp:26" >globalexceptions.cpp:26</a>
  3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
  4: main in <a href="file:///home/gumba/Projects/cpp/backup_helper/backup_helper-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_2_in_PATH__System__Debug/../backup_helper/main.cpp:35" >main.cpp:35</a>
```

I've done some research, and found the following information and advices:

- (**OK: Catch by reference**) "Technically, even when you catch an exception by reference, the compiler still uses pass by value. This is due to the fact that a catch never returns control to the caller, and is thus responsible for clean-up"
- (**OK: Have copy constructor**) "Objects that are thrown must have a publicly accessible copy-constructor. The compiler is allowed to generate code that copies the thrown object any number of times, including zero. However even if the compiler never actually copies the thrown object, it must make sure the exception class's copy constructor exists and is accessible"

According to GDB the copy constructor is not called. SIGABRT happens on *delete[] errorMessage*. I don't understand why. errorMessage seems to be properly initialized.

What is the reason of SIGABRT?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Use `std::string` and you don't need no rule-of-three :D

Comment: typically when the runtime aborts, it also prints an error message to stderr or stdout. but it sounds pretty likely that you have double free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
FatalError::FatalError(const char *pErrorMessage):
    errorMessage(pErrorMessage)
{}
```

You shouldn't just store that `const char*`, you should allocate enough size in your `errorMessage` member, and copy it there. Otherwise, in the destructor, you'll be `delete`ing the address of the string literal, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

Anyway, you shouldn't use pointers here. Just use `std::string`, which handles memory for you:

```
class FatalError {
public:
    FatalError(const char *msg) : errorMessage(msg) {}
    // Add an overload for std::strings
    FatalError(const std::string &msg) : errorMessage(msg) {}

    std::string errorMessage;
};
```

No need to implement copy assignment operator, copy constructor, nor destructor.

A better solution would be to use `std::runtime_error`, which is exactly the same as you implemented, and it's provided in the standard library:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int Config::readConfig(int argc_p, char *argv_p[])
{
    if ( argc_p != 2 )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Sick usage. Try: <file.ini>\n");
    }
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a C++ program has thrown an exception, and it is being handled by an exception handler, that handler (a `catch` block) **must not** throw **another** exception, because that would necessitate the handling of **two** exceptions at the same time, which is a bridge too far even for C++. However, if the handler does throw an exception, the punishment for the violation is `std::terminate`, which is probably translates to the SIGABRT you're seeing.

Using a complicated class such as you've defined for throwing exceptions is risky, because of the double-exception prohibition, and unnecessary: as mfontanini pointed out, you can just use `std::runtime_error`.